# Clear session and local storage for specific domain from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, session-storage

Is it possible to clear session and local storage for specific domain from a **chrome extension**?

Let's say I want to target the `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` for `somedomain.com`. The way I do this now is:

```
function clearSessionSotorage(key) {
  /**
   * Clears the session storage value for the given key
   * @param string key The key whose value should be cleared, if not provided, all keys are cleared for the current domain
   */
   var code = key ? 'window.sessionStorage.clear(' + key + ')' : 'window.sessionStorage.clear()';
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: code });
}

function clearLocalStorage(key) {
  /**
   * Clears the local storage value for the given key
   * @param string key The key whose value should be cleared, if not provided, all keys are cleared for the current domain
   */
  var code = key ? 'window.localStorage.clear(' + key + ')' : 'window.localStorage.clear()';
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: code });
}
```

This works as long as the *active tab* is open to a page on `somedomain.com`.

However, I'd like to target specific domains without the need to have that domain up in the active tab.

If it's possible, how can I do this?

I've considered cycling through all tabs looking for the target url, which would be an improvement, but really, I'd  prefer an option that avoids having to have the domain active at all.

Comment: I don't think you can do that as you're blocked by Same Origin Policy. Scripts in pages loaded from domain1 cannot access storage objects from domain2.

Comment: @Arkantos this is a chrome extension, it does not have this restriction...

Comment: @smnbbrv exactly, a lot of things are possible in this context that are not in a normal page. Im hoping this is one of those, nice catch on the edit BTW

Comment: @smnbbrv.. Good to know that. it would be helpful if you can provide some link explaining that. :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D, As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/clear), `clear()` will not accept any arguments and clears all storage items. If you want to remove a specific item from storage based on a key, use `sessionStorage.removeItem(key)` instead

Comment: @Arkantos I appreciate your willingness to help. The issue is not targeting specific keys, the issue is targeting specific *domains*. By design, the `Storage` API targets the currently active domain. I'm looking for a *technique* that will let me use this function to while targeting a domain of my choosing.

Comment: @Arkantos from the context of a chrome extension, we can inject code into pages in various ways. This allows us to get around a lot of the same origin issues and the like that one would otherwise face

Comment: Do you intend to clear session storage for a domain that's not active in any of the tabs or you just want to clear session storage from one of the tabs opened in your window but not necessarily the active tab ?

Comment: @Arkantos ideally I need to clear session storage for all tabs currently on the target domain and local storage for the domain itself

Comment: @DelightedD0D added a solution which does not need to open tabs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way is to loop all tabs and look for the target url, then remove the sessionStorage for that domain, or if you want, you can insert content scripts for specific domain, which would do clear sessionStorage logic.

When you said

> I'd prefer an option that avoids having to have the domain active at all

It seems you forgot the lifecycle of sessionStorage, according to [Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), **sessionStorage would be cleared when the tab/browser closed and won't be shared between tabs.**

> Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause **a new session to be initiated**

Comment: Ah, good catch. I did indeed mistake sessionStorage with  how session cookies work. Actually, I need to clear both session and local storage though. My appologies, I left it out originally because it didnt seem relavent considering they share the same API. But I did not consider this point. +1 though :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D, I see... As for both localStorage and sessionStorage, I believe the only way is to loop all tabs or insert content scripts for specific domains. However, we could wait for anyone else if they have better ideas :)

Comment: Agreed,  I'm thinking use the loop for the sessionStorage and for localStorage maybe open a    new window to the target URL without focus, inject the code, then close the window

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to clear sessionStorage/localStorage for a particular domain that is currently opened but not active in your browser window, then you need to execute some script in the context of that domain.

I think you can do this using a comibination of `chrome.tabs.query()`([link1](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)) and then `chrome.tabs.executeJavaScript()`([link2](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)) using code as string or using name of Content Script file.

```
chrome.tabs.query({
  'url' : 'target-domain.com'
});

chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'sessionStorage.clear()'
  });

(or)

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

For `url` property in tabs.query(), you can use patterns as mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns);

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed, there is a way with tabs where you can open a tab and run the code in there. But opening / closing tabs does not really sound a good solution...

After some investigation I have a small and quite working solution using IFRAME instead of tabs. Add this code to your `background.js`:

```
// create a URL suffix to make it unique and make nearly impossible to hit the existing page
var suffix = 'chrome-run-on-domain-' + chrome.runtime.id;

// if the domain is blocking displaying pages in IFRAME, remove the restriction
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
  return {
    responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders.filter(function(e) {
      return e.name.toUpperCase() !== 'X-FRAME-OPTIONS';
    })
  };
}, { urls: [ '*://*/' + suffix ] }, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);

// finally the function which does the job: it adds an IFRAME to the background page
function injectScript(protocol, domain) {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

  iframe.src = protocol + '://' + domain + '/' + suffix;

  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

// run the code
injectScript('https', 'www.google.de');
```

This code already makes a big chunk of the job. It creates an `iframe` on your background page which securely comes to the domain of your wish.

Then you need to create a file with changes you want to run on a page:

```
// actually any action to do with a session/localStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
localStorage.clear();

// important, stops the page loading
// this prevents unnecessary images / css / js calls on that page
// and prevents js redirects
window.stop();
```

Now it's time to set the references and permissions in your manifest file:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "background.js"
  ]
},
"content_scripts": [{
  "all_frames": true,
  "js": ["injectable.js"],
  "matches": ["*://*/chrome-run-on-domain-*"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}],
"permissions": [
  "<all_urls>",
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking"
]
```

What you have in the end: you can clear the `localStorage`, and not only. You don't open new tabs for that, so it goes quite smoothly. Still there are disadvantages (still the same problems will be existing on tabs solution):

1. there is no server side redirect (301 / 302 / etc) protection. If server will response with a redirect, it cannot really be intercepted.
2. there is still a server call. I tried to cancel the request (if that would work, there were no disadvantages at all) but unfortunately chrome does not allow to inject script into the cancelled request. `window.stop()` helps here but still...

It works even better with your initial method: you simply check first your tabs whether there is a page from your domain and if there is none use the method above.

Answer (score -2):

If your localStorage is coming from an iFrame, you can clear it by rubbing this code on your console.

```
$('.my_iframe')[0].contentWindow.localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: This question doesnt have anything to do with iframes so this answer doesnt really fit